# check if genisoimage is succesful

Tags: shell, shell-script

I use a script to convert all VIDEO_TS directories to .ISO.
How can I check if genisoimage is actually converting it instead of it failling and converting the next folder?

After conversion I have a command to delete the folder but if genisoimage fails then it still deletes it.

```
#!/bin/bash
iso_name=""
parent_path=""
full_path=""
total=0

IFS=$'\n'
clear

for file in $(find /shares/media/ -type d -name 'VIDEO_TS')
do

parent_path="$(dirname -- "$file")"
full_path="$file"
iso_name="$(basename -- "$parent_path").ISO"
iso_path=""$(dirname -- "$parent_path")"/"$iso_name""

echo "Converting to "$iso_name""

((total++))
genisoimage -allow-limited-size -o  "$iso_path" -dvd-video "$parent_path"
rm -rf "$parent_path" 

done

echo "Succesfully converted "$total" videos to ISO!"
```

Comment: I would start by looking at the exit code of genisoimage.

Comment: How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Every process has an [exit status](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status), which is a number between 0 and 255. There is a convention which is pretty much universally followed that 0 indicates success and anything else indicates failure¹.

In a shell script, the special variable `$?` contains the exit status of the last command. If you need to use it more than once, save it to another variable (otherwise the first command using it would set `$?` to its status).

Often, you don't need to use `$?`: you can make use of the shell's conditional constructs to react differently to zero and nonzero.

```
if genisoimage …; then
  rm rm -rf "$parent_path"
else
  echo 1>&2 "genisoimage failed, aborting"
  exit 2
fi
```

You can use `set -e` to switch the script to error-on-exit mode: if a simple command fails (i.e. returns a nonzero status), the script exits immediately, with the same exit status. For example, if you put `set -e` somewhere before the `for` loop, your script will exit immediately if `genisoimage` fails.

If you want to keep looping but record failures, save the current error count in a variable.

```
successes=0
failures=0
err=0
for file in $(find /shares/media/ -type d -name 'VIDEO_TS')
do
  parent_path="$(dirname -- "$file")"  # or parent_path=${file%/*}
  iso_path="$parent_path.ISO"
  echo "Converting to "$iso_name""
  genisoimage -allow-limited-size -o "$iso_path" -dvd-video "$parent_path"
  ret=$?
  if ((ret == 0)); then
    rm -rf "$parent_path"
    ((++successes))
  else
    ((++failures))
    if ((ret > err)); then ret=$err; fi
  fi
done
echo "Succesfully converted "$total" videos to ISO. There were $failures failures."
exit $err
```

¹  <sub>For search commands like `grep`, 0 means “found”, 1 means “not found” and other values mean “some error happened”.</sub>